# What does it mean to train a Naive Bayes classifier for categorical features?

Tags: classification, normal-distribution, categorical-data, continuous-data, naive-bayes

I know that Naive Bayes classifiers can be trained for both categorical and continuous (using a Gaussian distribution) features. I am less certain of how these two classifiers would differ. What does it mean to train for categorical features vs for continuous features?

Comment: Maybe this should help you https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/use-naive-bayes-algorithm-for-categorical-and-numerical-data-classification-935d90ab273f

Comment: Please consider this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218492/how-does-naive-bayes-work-with-continuous-variables to avoid duplications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Naive Bayes work with continuous variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218492/how-does-naive-bayes-work-with-continuous-variables)