# NaiveBayes in R - Understand importance of Variables

Tags: r, classification, naive-bayes

I am working with a data set where the response variable is binary and 15-20 continuous and categorical variables.

I am using the naiveBayes library to compute the model. I am interested in understanding which of the independent variables are the most important as well as trying to better understand the model outputs (below as example).

[image]

I've done a lot of research but I am not having any luck. Any perspective would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Can you explain why you chose Naive Bayes, esp. since you have continuous predictors? NB is not the most natural fit for continuous features (as hinted in a way by *Age[,1]* and *Age[,2]*). NB also makes very strong assumptions. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/218492/237901) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/47027/70959).

Comment: Fair point. The majority of the variables are categorical with only a few that are continuous.

I am testing out various methods to predict and better understand what variables have a stronger impact/influence on a response variable that is binary. Based on my research, it looks like naive bayes might be a good option.